# Tensor product (confusing question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let's say I have a tensor product $A\otimes B$ of algebras $A,B$.

I have a linearly independent subset $S\subseteq A\otimes B$ such that $span(S)\cong C$, where $C$ is another algebra.

Similarly, there is another linearly independent subset $T\subseteq A\otimes B$ such that $span(T)\cong D$, where $D$ is another algebra.

We also have that $ST=\sum s_it_j, s_i\in S, t_j\in T$ is a basis for $A\otimes B$, $cd=dc$ for all $c\in C, d\in D$.

Eventually I want to show that $A\otimes B\cong C\otimes D$. Are the above conditions enough? If not, what are the minimal additional assumptions that allow me to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean $ST = (s_it_j)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the dimensions : $\dim(C) = |S|$, $\dim(D) = |T|$, and $\dim(A\otimes B) = |S|+|T|$.

But then $\dim(C\otimes D) = |S|\cdot |T|\neq \dim(A\otimes B)$ (if the dimesnions are finite).

Comment: Upvoted, thanks. I changed the question to $ST$ a basis, sorry for the typo.